# Having one counter per section and print the total in the title of the section

Tags: counters, totcount

I'm trying to have a individual counter per section (like its done in the second answer of [How to read counter value from every section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645283/how-to-read-counter-value-from-every-section#new-answer?newreg=c95e1218186e46ea94f34898153c47dd)) but I want to print the final value of the counter in the title of the section (like what would be done with the totcount package).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\incrementCounter{2}%We increment the section counter
\incrementCounter{1}
%section counter has value 3

\section{Second section}
\incrementCounter{1}
%section counter has value 1
\end{document}
```

should display

```
1 First section 3
2 Second section 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on the terrible answer mentioned in your question and uses `totcount`.

In case you uncomment the `\pagestyle{headings}` call or otherwise use a class whose headers are subject to `\MakeUppercase`, a recent LaTeX kernel is required, such as `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 1` (this is for `\l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{totcount}
% \usepackage{lipsum}             % for the dummy text

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\ocalexIncr}[2]{%
  \edef\ocalex@ctrname{ocalex@#1@ctr@\number\value{section}}%
  \@ifundefined{c@\ocalex@ctrname}
    {\newcounter{\ocalex@ctrname}%
     \expandafter\regtotcounter\expandafter{\ocalex@ctrname}%
    }{}%
  \addtocounter{\ocalex@ctrname}{\numexpr (#2) - 1\relax}%
  \refstepcounter{\ocalex@ctrname}%
  %(\csuse{the\ocalex@ctrname})% uncomment to show the current counter value
}

\newcommand*{\mytotal}[1]{%
  \protect\total{ocalex@#1@ctr@\number\value{section}}%
}

% Redefinition: automatically append “\nobreakspace \mytotal{foo}” to
% numbered \section titles.
\NewCommandCopy{\ocalex@orig@section}{\section}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \section { s O{#3} m }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      % No automatic addition for unnumbered sections
      { \ocalex@orig@section* {#3} }
      {
        \ocalex@orig@section
          [ { #2\nobreakspace \mytotal{foo} } ]
          {   #3\nobreakspace \mytotal{foo} }
      }
  }

% This is for \pagestyle{headings} and requires a recent LaTeX format
\tl_if_in:NnF \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \total }
  { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \total } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother

% As many such counters as you want. 'foo' is used in \incrementCounter and in
% the above redefinition of \section, in order to comply with the document
% markup from the question.
\newcommand*{\incrementCounter}{\ocalexIncr{foo}}

% \pagestyle{headings}       % this works

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents             % this also works

% That would have been a reasonable syntax, but the question doesn't want it.
% \section{First section~\mytotal{foo}}
\section{First section}
\incrementCounter{2}
\incrementCounter{1}
% \lipsum[1-10]               % uncomment to test with \pagestyle{headings}

\section{Second section}
\incrementCounter{1}
% \lipsum[1-3]                % uncomment to test with \pagestyle{headings}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much! Why to you say the answer is terrible?

Comment: Because it was mine and no one upvoted it... Glad to hear to liked this one!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: Yes I know, don't worry. :-)